# Pause scrolling up on hover

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to put scrolling up behavior in WordPress. I am unable to get success in pausing  when mouse hover on it. I have tried jQuery and CSS (paused) method but all in vain. any help is highly appreciated. Here is my code (CSS):

```
.sliderz {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    animation: sliderz linear infinite;
}

.sliderz li { line-height: 50px; width: 100vw; } 

@keyframes sliderz {
    0%   { transform: translateY(100vh) }
    100% { transform: translateY(-100%) }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class=sliderz>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
window.onload = function() {
var lineHeight = document.querySelector(".sliderz li").clientHeight;
var viewHeight = window.innerHeight;
var sliderz = document.querySelector(".sliderz");
var time = (sliderz.offsetHeight * 2.0 + viewHeight * 2) / 100.0; // 500px / sec

sliderz.style.animationDuration = time + "s";
}
```

I am trying to put jQuery something like this but it is not working on it.

```
var sL = 4000;
$('.sliderz').animate({
    scrollup : su
},100000, 'linear');

$(".sliderz").on("click",function(){
        $(this).stop(true,false);
});

$(".sliderz").on("mouseenter",function(){
    $(this).stop(true,false);
});

$(".sliderz").on("mouseleave",function(){
    $(this).animate({
    scrollup : su
    },100000, 'linear');
});
```

I am stuck here badly. Thanks in advance

Comment: what happens on "click"? Does it work like intended or is it both "mouseenter" and "click" that do not work?. Also, does it just not stop the animation or does it something else entirely. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: on mouse hover nothing happened. i want it to pause slideup scroll text when mouse hover over it.

Comment: did you try $(".sliderz").on("mousehover", ...)  instead of mouseenter? Seems to me like you want the animation to stop as long as the mouse is hovered over. see https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/#mouseover-handler

Comment: i tried this but nothing happened, may be some syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paused specifies that the animation is paused. You can use like :

```
.sliderz:hover {
animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sections {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.section1,
.section2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
}

.sliderz {
  clear: both;
  height: 100vh;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  animation: sliderz 5s linear infinite;
}

.sliderz li {
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
}

@keyframes sliderz {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100vh)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%)
  }
}

.sliderz:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="sections">
  <div class="section1">Section1</div>
  <div class="section2">Section2</div>
  <div class="section3">
    <div class=sliderz>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have edited some code. You can have a look at this... Is that you wanted or not??

Comment: WoW @Ishita Ray you are Rock. i was still searching for a way to do this but unable to get suceess from more than 6hours.. Bundles of thanks you save my day :)

Comment: i am facing little bit issue. i am trying to implement it in wordpress column, overflow Y is written as hidden but it is still going away from column to top side. slso starting point is also from far bottom and takes time to display. any help plz?

Comment: Then you need query... :|

Comment: i have used your code in my page. only issue is that upward scrolling content is not hidding and moving above the column.